# Answers and Timing

Tags: discussion

We're starting to get more detailed and area specific questions, especially regarding Europe (including the British Isles).

How many "experts" do we have in these geographic locations?  Can anyone recruit expert friends to chime in?

Answer (score 3):

I'm in the UK, and have tried to encourage a couple of others to join too - I wouldn't go as far as saying I'm an expert, but I try to answer those sorts of questions where I can.

Comment: You're the closest thing we have to an UK expert, and you're active :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm definitely not an expert, but have been encouraged to enjoy the outdoors since about the age of 4, dad being a keen explorer/greenpeace/wilderness kind of guy.

I live in Scotland but have camped in the Falklands, Scottish Highlands, central Germany and various other locations round the UK and Scandinavia, both on my own and with kids from the age of 18 months upwards, so have reasonable experience in the requirements of such camping.

Additionally, the training with the Scouts in the Falklands and the Sea Cadets in Orkney, as well as being a sailing instructor has given good grounding in the planning for normal and emergency scenarios both on land and at sea.